# How to make Machinarium work again?

Tags: 32-bit

I am on Ubuntu 12.04 (64b) and bought Machinarium a while ago. I played with no problems for some days and wanted to play again today. However, when I tried to play, I got this error:

```
./Machinarium: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a 32-bit binary and requires the 32-bit version of libgtk. Make sure that the package libgtk2.0-0:i386 is installed.

```
sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386
```

Update:

Though you'll need other libraries as well and if that library is missing, the other 32-bit libraries are probably missing as well, thus

```
sudo apt-get install ia32-libs
```

ia32-libs depend on a lot of 32-bit libraries which gets installed when you install it.

Comment: Installed that. Now I get this one: ./Machinarium: error while loading shared libraries: libnss3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: @Cmorales ia32-libs appears to depend on a lot of 32-bit libraries. Likely it installs all the necessary libraries to run Machinarium, so try `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: It worked! Thanks! PS: Wow, 150MB to make it work... and it worked before without that!?

Comment: @Cmorales most likely you had those libraries installed earlier, but they got uninstalled at some point (one possible scenario is that you uninstalled some 32-bit app, and apt thought "Oh, there doesn't seem to be any 32-bit apps installed any more, might as well remove the 32-bit libraries as well then"). Machinarium doesn't have a deb-package as far as I know, so apt doesn't know about it.

Answer (score 1):

`ia32-libs` is obsolote in the latest Ubuntu versions. To fix Machinarium, install the missing 32 bit libraries this way:

```
sudo apt-get install libnss3.s:i386 libcurl3:i386 libgtk2.0-0:i386
```